# How to setup a song when starting Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, music

I was wondering if it was possible to start a mp3 song in one of three places:

1. After starting the computer from cold, when the Ubuntu logo appears (When loading the system).
2. When I enter the LightDM greeter.
3. When I enter the desktop after entering my user/pass in the greeter.

As a bonus maybe run a playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 and 3 are quite easy (See below). Number 1 could be possible but I don't really know much about plymouth.

First off, create a small shell script containing these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
mpg123 -q $1 &
```

I chose to save it as `/usr/local/bin/play-sound` (Also make sure mpg123 is installed).
You can use any command-line player you like. The `&` at the end of the line is imortant since lightdm will wait untill the script finishes. And we want the sound to play during lightdm. And the `$1` will be replaced by whaterver file we specify when executing the script later on. Also remember to `chmod +x` the script.

2 ) Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and set `greeter-setup-script=play-sound <file.mp3>` somewhere in the `[SeatDefaults]` section. Make sure the mp3 is accessible for all (not in an encrypted home folder or such). Don't use a long file as it will play it until the end.

3 ) Run `gnome-session-properties` from a terminal or run-dialog. Click `Add`, enter a nifty name, set the command to `play-sound <file.mp3>`. Add a comment if you want. Click `Add` and then `Close`. This will make the selected file play when the current user logs in. If you want the file to play for all users just move the resulting file from `$HOME/.config/autostart/` to `/usr/share/gnome/autostart/`. I might add that there are more ways to set a login-sound for gnome. This is just a quick way.

I have tested these two solutions in ubuntu 11.10 running gnome-shell and unity. If I get some time over I will look in to the matter of running audio when plymouth runs. Or if anyone else knows ho to do this feel free to join in.

Comment: Please look into it Zoke since it is not yet clear how to do it.

Comment: Added some more info for you now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to set custom sound. But you can hack it.  ubuntu run files from /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo so place your desire file and rename it(File format ogg).

As an example if you want to change login sound then replace desktop-login.ogg with your file.